# Finding extremum in a polynomial function

Tags: functions

A function given by $f(x)=\frac{(ax^2+2bx+c)}{(Ax^2+2Bx+C)}$ has points of extrema at $x=1$ and $x=-1$, such that $f(1)=2, f(-1)=3$ and $f(0)=2.5$. Then

1. Which of the following is true?

   - (A) $a= -2.5A$
   - (B) $a=  2.5A$
   - (C) $A= -2.5A$
   - (D) none of these
2. Which of the following is true?

   - (A) $b=B$
   - (B) $A=B$
   - (C) $c=C$
   - (D) $A=C$
3. What is the function? (in terms of $P/Q$, where $P$ and $Q$ are quadratic polynomials)

Comment: Again: latex. Also: when asking questions, try to do some work before asking, and afterwards post your thoughts, intuitions and ideas along with the question.

Comment: Having points of extrema at $x=1$ and $x=-1$ means that the derivative is $0$ at those points. In other words $(2ax+2b)(Ax^2+2B+C)-(2Ax+2B)(ax^2+2bx+c)$ has roots at $x=-1,1$

Comment: yes i tried that but it makes it much complicated. What could be the next step?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** From $f(0)=2.5$, you get $c = 2.5C$.
Similarly make equations using $f(1)=2,f(-1)=3, f^1(1)=0, f^1(-1)=0$

Comment: yea, that's where i got too

Comment: i just got lost in equations. i found a in terms of A,B,C and b in terms of A,B,C and obviously c (=2.5C)

Comment: solved it! Just differentiate and put equal to zero at critical points. Substitute x=1, whatever and then use relation obtained by putting 1 whatever in f(x). Got it long ago but posting it now